# Worker not defined when I try to run mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, web-worker

I want to write test script to check whether Worker gets created in a function in some external file. The function I want to test is,

```
createPoller: function () {
  var poller = new Worker(POLLER_PATH),
      _this = this;


  /* worker handler on receiving the message */
  poller.onmessage = this.handlePoller.bind(_this);
  this.set('pollerId', U.generateUUID());
  this.set('poller', poller);
}
>>> ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
at new Worker(POLLER_PATH)
      ^
```

When I run the code, workers are created and they work fine. But when I run script on that particular code it says Worker is undefined.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what environment you are running your tests in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JavaScript environment you use supports web workers natively, then they should just be *there* for you to use, and your code should work. So the most probable issue is that you are in fact running your code in a JavaScript environment that does not support web workers natively. If you want to use web workers in Node.js, for instance, you'd have to add a [library that provides it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads). According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker), IE does not support web workers before version 10.

Comment: If I run the code, then the workers are working fine. But when I try to run a test script on that code, it says Workers is undefined.